# Spacemacs keybinding to execute shell script in directory the file in the current windows buffer is located in

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs

I need a keybinding (either a key like `F12` or a mnemonic key sequence like `SPC f12`) in Spacemacs. When hitting the keybinding in a window containing a file in its buffer the shell script `script` in the directory the file is located in shall be executed.

Which one of the alternatives to define key bindings should I use? I thought about calling a function when the key binding is triggered. How could I get the directory the file in the current window buffer is located in when this function is executed? But probably there is another way to solve this problem.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: I added questions which relate to a possible solution I thought about. I hope this makes the overall question more clear.

Comment: Buffers with non-nil `(buffer-file-name)` have the variable [`default-directory`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Expansion.html) set to the directory of the file. In most cases that is what `(file-name-directory (buffer-file-name))` returns. Do you mean that by "root directory of the file in buffer"? Note that for a Linux user the wording "root directory of file in buffer" looks somewhat strange. AFAIK, there the root directory always is `/`.

Comment: The [docs - Reserved prefix command for user](http://spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#reserved-prefix-command-for-user) state that `SPC o` and `SPC m o` are guaranteed to never conflict with default bindings and which are reserved for users. Can be used instead of e.g. `(global-set-key [f12] 'run-script)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an executable script called `script` the solution is to put the following code into the `user-config` section of the `~/.spacemacs` file.
The [reserved prefix command for users](http://spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#reserved-prefix-command-for-user) is either `SPC o` or `SPC m o`. These bindings are guaranteed to never conflict with default key bindings. Hitting `SPC o` show the user specific key bindings. Hitting `SPC o s` executes the script.

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()

...

  (defun run-script ()
    (interactive)
    (shell-command "$PWD/.script"))
  (spacemacs/set-leader-keys "os" 'run-script)

...

)
```